# Getting "Failed to find provider info for ContentProvider" error

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm creating a simple ContentProvider to access the data in my SQLite3 database. Although I've declared the provider in my AndroidManifest.xml file I'm getting "Failed to find provider info for
com.tur_cirdictionary.turkishcircassiandictionary".

What is the problem here?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml and ContentProvider files.
[This](https://github.com/SametSahin10/turkish-circassian-dictionary) is the Github link for the project if needed.

```
//AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tur_cirdictionary.turkish_circassiandictionary">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ArchiveActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Searchable">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".Searchable" />
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="com.tur_cirdictionary.turkish_circassiandictionary.data.WordProvider"
        android:authorities=
            "com.tur_cirdictionary.turkish_circassiandictionary"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

```
//WordProvider.java

package com.tur_cirdictionary.turkish_circassiandictionary.data;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import static com.tur_cirdictionary.turkish_circassiandictionary.data.WordContract.BASE_CONTENT_URI;
import static com.tur_cirdictionary.turkish_circassiandictionary.data.WordContract.WordEntry;

public class WordProvider extends ContentProvider {

public static final String LOG_TAG = WordProvider.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int WORDS = 100;
private static final int WORD_ID = 101;

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {

    sUriMatcher.addURI(WordContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, WordContract.PATH_WORDS, WORDS);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(WordContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, WordContract.PATH_WORDS
            + "/#", WORD_ID);

}

private WordDbHelper wordDbHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    wordDbHelper = new WordDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection,
                    @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = wordDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor;

    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (match) {

        case WORDS:
            cursor = database.query(WordEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

            break;

        case WORD_ID:
            selection = WordEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};

            cursor = database.query(WordEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);

    }

    return cursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {

    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (match) {

        case WORDS:
            return WordEntry.CONTENT_LIST_TYPE;

        case WORD_ID:
            return WordEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;

        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown URI " + uri + " with match" + match);

    }

}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values) {

    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (match) {

        case WORDS:
            return insertWord(uri, values);

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported for " + uri);

    }

}

@Override
public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection,
                  @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {

    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

    SQLiteDatabase database = wordDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    switch (match) {

        case WORDS:
            return database.delete(WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);

        case WORD_ID:
            long wordId = ContentUris.parseId(uri);

            selection = WordEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(wordId)};

            return database.delete(WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete is not supported for " + uri);

    }

}

@Override
public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {

    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (match) {

        case WORDS:
            return updateWord(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);

        case WORD_ID:
            long wordId = ContentUris.parseId(uri);

            selection = WordEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs  = new String[] {String.valueOf(wordId)};

            return updateWord(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Update is not supported for " + uri);

    }

}

private Uri insertWord(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

    if (values.containsKey(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CIRCASSIAN)) {

        String circassian = values.getAsString(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TURKISH);

        if (circassian == null) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word requires circassian translation");

        }

    }

    if (values.containsKey(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TURKISH)) {

        String turkish = values.getAsString(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TURKISH);

        if (turkish == null) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word requires turkish translation");

        }

    }

    if (values.size() > 0) {

        return null;

    }

    SQLiteDatabase database = wordDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    long idOfNewlyInserted = database.insert(WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    if (idOfNewlyInserted == -1) {

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to insert row for: " + uri);

        return null;

    }

    return ContentUris.withAppendedId(BASE_CONTENT_URI, idOfNewlyInserted);

}

private int updateWord(Uri uri, ContentValues values,
                       String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    if (values.containsKey(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CIRCASSIAN)) {

        String circassian = values.getAsString(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CIRCASSIAN);

        if (circassian == null) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Circassian translation required ");

        }

    }

    if (values.containsKey(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TURKISH)) {

        String turkish = values.getAsString(WordEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TURKISH);

        if (turkish == null) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Turkish translation required");

        }

    }

    if (values.size() < 0) {

        return 0;

    }

    SQLiteDatabase database = wordDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return database.update(WordEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);

}

}
```

Comment: The authority you used in the manifest ends in ".turkish_circassiandictionary" while the authority string you use in WordContract ends in ".turkishcircassiandictionary"

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the CONTENT_AUTHORITY String to the

> com.tur_cirdictionary.turkish_circassiandictionary

making it same with the package name. That solved the problem.